# Tracking keyboard input

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm developing simple game using c#/xaml. I want to implement game control using keyboard arrow keys. So I tried to implement KeyDown/KeyUp events on Page class, but it didn't fire.

Does anyone have ideas why it doesn't work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just found solution for my problem. You need hook up these events like this in constructor:

```
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyDown += App_KeyDown;
Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().KeyUp += App_KeyUp;
```